# Modifying an area of elements between two opposite reversible points in a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to write a method that given two `Point(X,Y)` of range 0 to 1000: `_startCoord` and `_endCoord`. Cycle through a 2D array `lightMap` from the `_startCoord` to the `_endCoord`, modifying each element in the area between the two points.

I've made this illustration as an example, I'm trying to modify all the elements within quad A, given: `_startCoord` as some corner Point and `_endCoord` as the opposite corner Point

[image: LightMap 2D array]

I've been trying to figure out a method that works in any "direction", for example:

From `500,500 to 250,750` WHERE x decrements, y increments

or `500,500 to 750,150`WHERE x increments, y decrements etc

**Here's my latest attempt:**

```cs
struct Point {
    public int xPos;
    public int yPos;
    public Point(int _x, int _y) {
        xPos = _x;
        yPos = _y;
    }
}

//Given two corner points, toggle the elements between the points 
static void ToggleBits(Point _startCoord, Point _endCoord) {
    //Determine direction to iterate on each axis
    int xDir = (_startCoord.xPos > _endCoord.xPos) ? -1 : 1;
    int yDir = (_startCoord.yPos > _endCoord.yPos) ? -1 : 1;
    int currentX = _startCoord.xPos;
    int currentY = _startCoord.yPos;
    //Account for single point (points are the same)
    if (_startCoord.xPos == _endCoord.xPos && _startCoord.yPos == _endCoord.yPos) {
        lightMap[currentX, currentY] = !lightMap[currentX, currentY]; //Toggle element at current indices
        return;
    }
    //While both indices not met
    while (currentX != _endCoord.xPos || currentY != _endCoord.yPos) {
        Console.WriteLine(currentX + ","+currentY);
        lightMap[currentX, currentY] = !lightMap[currentX, currentY]; //Toggle element at current indices
        if (currentX == _endCoord.xPos) { //Reached endX
            if (currentY != _endCoord.yPos) {  //But not reached endY
                currentY += yDir;            //Increment y axis
                currentX = _startCoord.xPos; //Return to column start
            }
        }
        else if (currentY == _endCoord.yPos) { //Reached endY
            if (currentX != _endCoord.xPos) { //But not reached endX
                currentX += xDir;            //Increment x axis
                currentY = _startCoord.yPos; //Return to row start
            }
        } else { //Neither indices reached increment x axis
            currentX += xDir; //Increment x axis
        }
    }
}
```

**Input**

```cs
ToggleBits(new Point(5,0), new Point(6,10));
```

[image: Illustrated Input]

**Output**

```
5,0
6,0
5,1
6,1
5,2
6,2
5,3
6,3
5,4
6,4
5,5
6,5
5,6
6,6
5,7
6,7
5,8
6,8
5,9
6,9
5,10
6,0
5,1
6,1
5,2
6,2
...Infinite Loop...
```

It is so close to working correctly, but as I reset the row/column and increment the column/row, I reset the progress and do it again...forever. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand, what you are trying to do, but can't you just go in two nested for-loops from the min to the max?

```
var minX = Math.Min(_startCoord.X, _endCoord.X);
var maxX = Math.Max(_startCoord.X, _endCoord.X);
var minY = Math.Min(_startCoord.Y, _endCoord.Y);
var maxY = Math.Max(_startCoord.Y, _endCoord.Y);
for (var x = minX; x < maxX; x++)
{
    for (var y = minY; y < maxY; y++)
    {
         // do something to lightMap[x, y]
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn that's embarrassing, I tried a less elegant version of this by using the ternary operator instead of Min/Max, but couldn't get the logic right. Changing the operators to `<=` and this works perfectly, thank you